# to_timestamp -- ends in 04 or 05

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pg database that has data for:

```
(yyyymmdd) hour (hh) minute (mm) and second (ss)
```

all in separate string type columns.

I used a function like this to get it to the timestamp type.. except the results are "to_timestamp with time zone"

```
to_timestamp(txdt||hh||mm||ss, 'YYYYDDMMHH24MISS')
```

They all seem to be correct but I am unsure of the 04 and 05 at the end of each timestamp. Like this:

"2011-03-04 23:59:50-05"
"2011-04-04 00:00:18-04"

What do the 04 and 05 mean? I presume time zones, however, I am not sure if these two were in reverse order or the order that they are in could would the closer date change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are the time zones at that date depending on when the [dayligth saving time](http://www.worldtimezone.com/daylight.html) time zone is in effect.

To have a timestamp without time zone:

```
to_timestamp(txdt||hh||mm||ss, 'YYYYDDMMHH24MISS')::timestamp without time zone
```

Comment: Ok.. If I wanted to remove the timezone how would I go about doing that? I've googled around for a bit now and couldn't find a concrete example..